# Google Sitemap Generator

Tags: sitemaps

I've got an 11 multi site situation where I have the sitemaps auto generated every day at 4am. It works fine but when I change the generation settings to weekly it still produces a fresh set of sitemap files each morning at 4am.

Any ideas why it would do this?

Comment: Can you please specify the Magento version you are running ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good reason to why the `Frequency` field is ignored when generating a sitemap.
**It's a bug**.

The problem is in `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Sitemap_Cron`. That's the backend model called when saving the sitemap generation settings.
The `frequency` is retrieved like this:

```
$frequncy = $this->getData('groups/generate/frequency/value');
```

This always returns `null`. (Also the var name is misspelled but that's not important).
The value should be retrieved like this:

```
$frequncy = $this->getData('groups/generate/fields/frequency/value');
```

There is a `fields` missing in there.
Here they are side by side so you can compare:

```
$frequncy = $this->getData('groups/generate/frequency/value'); //how it's done
$frequncy = $this->getData('groups/generate/fields/frequency/value'); // how it should be
```

I don't know what version are you using but I can confirm this is still wrong in `ce-1.8.1.0` (and `ce-1.7.0.2`)

**On a side note:** the values for `$enabled` and `$errorEmail` are retrieved wrongly also, but they are not used in the same model